# Save toggle state of different buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a class called `hidden` which hides (obviously)
I wanted to toggle its visibility, but the problem is I won't be toggling one div but multiple divs.
So I assigned a button for each div, which works btw

```
<script>
$(".hidden").hide();

function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("."+divId).toggle();
 }
 </script>

<div class="hidden biographies">
...
</div>

<div class="hidden food">
...
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('biographies')">Bios</button>

<button id="button" onclick="javascript:toggleDiv('food')">Food</button>
```

How can I save the toggle state using cookies?

I'm sorry if you saw this before, I tried implementing the other examples found on this site but since am not familiar with JS I ended up seeking help, thank you in advance

Comment: u can use the jquery cookie plugin.

Comment: i tried, that's what I need help with..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) instead cookies.

Here is an example of how to **write** and **read** values using your code:

```
$(function() {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('visible')){ //read the value, if the value does not exist it will return false.
      $('.hidden').hide();
    }

    function toggleDiv(divId) {
      $('.' + divId).toggle();

      localStorage.setItem('visible', $('.' + divId).is('::visible')); // save value to local storage
    }
});
```

Check `localStorage` support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage).

Comment: Where do I put that retrieve line?

Comment: @atp If you want to check the value an then hide or show the divs depending on that value you can write the code inside your script tag. You have to read the visibility value and then check if the div should be hidden or not. Check the answer again.

Comment: thank you for the help @ianaya89 I got this error on the console `Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ::visible` I must be missing something

Comment: @atp Try using only one ':' --> $('.' + divId).is(':visible')